# Prometheus alert rule: parse error: unexpected character: '|'

Tags: prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I've got a loki metric expression, which I can use in grafana without any errors:

```
avg_over_time({filename="/home/obey/var/log/domains.metric"} |= "dns_auth_ns_daemon" | logfmt | unwrap success | __error__="" [10m]) == 0
```

[image]

However, if I try to use this expression for an alert, I get an error from `promtool`. Here's the alert rule:

```
groups:
- name: nagitics-exporter
  rules:

  - alert: DomainServed
    expr: avg_over_time({filename="/home/obey/var/log/domains.metric"} |= "dns_auth_ns_daemon" | logfmt | unwrap success | __error__="" [10m]) == 0
    for: 10m
    labels:
      severity: critical
    annotations:
      summary: Zone {{ $labels.hostname }} not served anymore
      description: "Zone {{ $labels.hostname }} does not return a proper authoritative NS record: {{ $labels.raw }}"
```

Error message:

```
Checking rule-nagitics-promtail.yml
  FAILED:
rule-nagitics-promtail.yml: 6:11: group "nagitics-exporter", rule 1, "DomainServed": could not parse expression: 1:62: parse error: unexpected character: '|'
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: Where are you seeing this message? Is it in the Loki log? Or in the Promtail one? I didn't understand.

Comment: The error message comes from `promtool check`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[LogQL](https://grafana.com/docs/loki/latest/logql/) != [PromQL](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/)

Alertmanager and `promtool` use PromQL.

Comment: Ok, I added the rule to loki rules. Thanks!